# Android notification click restore activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have MainActivity and WorkActivity in my app. WorkActivity starting by MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WorkActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("intArray", intArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

In WorkActivity I read intArray param and start foreground service with notification:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int[] intArray = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("intArray");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra("intArray", intArray);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Service notification:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, WorkActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newIntent, 0);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("title)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentText("text");
Notification notification;
notification = builder.build();
startForeground(1, notification);
```

Now, when I close my app and click to notification occur error, because WorkActivity can't get

```
getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("intArray");
```

that should bу passed by MainActivity.
How to fix this?

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test.MyService@9051e18 with Intent { cmp=com.test/.MyService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
```

Error occur because WorkActivity.getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("intArray") is null.
Activity send this to service in lines:

```
intent.putExtra("intArray", intArray);
startService(intent);
```

In service I need to get some numbers from intArray like intArray[0], but intArray is null

Comment: Pls add your logcat to the question

Comment: There's a wealth of information already on passing variables, objects through notifications: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=android+notifications+passing+variable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to the notification bar and select the notification, this starts a new instance of `WorkActivity`. This instance of `WorkActivity` is not started from your `MainActivity`, but by the notification, and the `Intent` you put in the notification does not have the extra `intArray`.

Basically you need to add the `putExtra()` call for `intArray` into this code:

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, WorkActivity.class);
    // HERE YOU NEED TO CALL newIntent.putExtra("intArray", intArray);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newIntent, 0);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("title)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setContentText("text");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
WorkActivity have line

    startService(intent);

and when WorkActivity create after notificaton click, service started one more time. How to avoid this?

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirement, but if you want `WorkActivity` to know that it has been started from a notification (in case the behaviour should be different), you can add another "extra" to the `Intent` that you put in the notification. Then, `WorkActivity` can check this "extra" to determine if it has been started from a notification.

Comment: Ok, that's what I need. Thank you